# storing failes: binmode() on closed filehandle $out at ... print() on closed filehandle $out

Tags: perl, filehandle

see the **update** at the end of the intail posting

- well i am a bit confued i have to admit...;-) being a novice perl-friend the perl-code   allway looks a bit abracadaba....

i need to have some thumbnails from websites but i tried to use wget - but that does not work for me, since i need some rendering functions what is needet: i have a list of 2,500 URLs, one on each line, saved in a file. Then i want a script - see it below - to open the file, read a line, then retrieve the website and save the image as a small thumbnail. well since i have a bunch of web-sites (2500) i have to make up my mind about the naming of the results.

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
http://www.phtg.ch
http://www.phsg.ch
http://www.phsh.ch
http://www.phr.ch
http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
```

So far so 
good, well i think i try something like this

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

  my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

  open my $urls, '<', 'urls.txt' or die $!;

  while (<$urls>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /^http/i;
    print "$_\n";
    $mech->get($_);
    my $png = $mech->content_as_png;
    my $name = $_;
    $name =~ s#^http://##i;
    $name =~ s#/##g;
    $name =~ s/\s+\z//;
    $name =~ s/\A\s+//;
    $name =~ s/^www\.//;
    $name .= ".png";
  open(my $out, '>', "/images/$name");
  binmode $out;
    print $out $png;
    close $out;
    sleep 5;
  }
```

i get the following results now....
see what comes out... 
and as far as i can see - there are no images stored in the folder "images"

why not!?

```
rtin@linux-wyee:~> cd perl
martin@linux-wyee:~/perl> perl test_8.pl
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 2.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 2.
http://www.zug.phz.ch
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 3.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 3.
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 4.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 4.
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 5.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 5.
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 6.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 6.
http://www.phvs.ch
binmode() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 25, <$urls> line 14.
print() on closed filehandle $out at test_8.pl line 26, <$urls> line 14.                                                                                        http://www.pfh-gr.ch                                                                       Got status code 500 at test_8.pl line 15                                                                                         martin@linux-wyee:~/perl>
```

what does the output want to say to me...
what can i do now!?

**update**

hello my dear

thx  for the reply - guess that i have a permission issue here....

well i have this...

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl
  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

  my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

  open my $urls, '<', 'urls.txt' or die $!;

  while (<$urls>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /^http/i;
    print "$_\n";
    $mech->get($_);
    my $png = $mech->content_as_png;
    my $name = $_;
    $name =~ s#^http://##i;
    $name =~ s#/##g;
    $name =~ s/\s+\z//;
    $name =~ s/\A\s+//;
    $name =~ s/^www\.//;
    $name .= ".png";
  open(my $out, '>', "/images $name")or die $!;
  binmode $out;
    print $out $png;
    close $out;
    sleep 5;
  }
```

well this works - but all i can get is the storing into the directory where the test_8.pl resides

guess that this is a permission issue.

what can i do.

can i put the image-directory somewhere outside the folder of perl..?
perhaps i have created either the

perl-directory or the 
images-directory with some special root permission.

what i did to solve the issues so far was

a- checkint the permissions on the folders 
- perl 
. perl/images

b.- running the script in command line as root user.

well allll i can get are the results that are stored in the folder,...

```
linux-wyee:/home/martin/perl_dev/perl # ls
.directory                    images                    module_test         pfh-gr.ch.png  phsg.ch.png          phtg.ch.png  schwyz.phz.ch.png  test_4.pl  test_8.pl        urls.txt
heilpaedagogik.phbern.ch.png  luzern.phz.ch.png         module_test.pl      phbern.ch.png  phsh.ch.png          phvs.ch.png  test_2.pl          test_6.pl  test_8.pl~       zug.phz.ch.png
hepfr.ch.png                  ma-shp.luzern.phz.ch.png  open-local-file.pl  phr.ch.png     ph-solothurn.ch.png  .png         test_3.pl          test_7.pl  unifr.chsfm.png
linux-wyee:/home/martin/perl_dev/perl #
```

the images folder is empty

what can i do

sould i create a images folder outside the perl-directory

how to name the string-path to it..?!

dear buddy - we re allmost there - i am pretty sure - i guess that this is only a permission issue.  But how to solve it!?

perhaps i have to create all the testfiles in a whole new directory again . not as root but as normal user!? What do you say!?

Comment: The statement `open(my $out, '>', "/images/$name")` appears to be failing add `or die $!` to troubleshoot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [perl-mechanize runs into limitations - several debugging attempts started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656892/perl-mechanize-runs-into-limitations-several-debugging-attempts-started)

Comment: hello .- see the update at the inital posting - guess that you are right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You weren't able to open the file for writing. Your path is */images*, and you probably don't have permissions on that directory (if it even exists). Always check the return value of your calls to [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), like you did in the first [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

If I were you, I wouldn't use */images*. I'd download everything into directory I control and isn't cluttering the standard directory layouts. You should almost never create new directories under */* if you aren't doing system administration.

Comment: hello dear brian d foy mana thanks - well ou are right - i check the permissions - and i hope that afterwards it goes well. thx again for all you did. many many greetings -

Comment: **update**  well i changed the permissions and tried it again - it still  fails... Note: there was a version of the script were the files werent written in an extra folder -that one runned well. **why?**

Comment: hello brain hello all - see the update at the intial posting... i guess that you are right

Comment: hello brian thx for the answer - i think youre right. Convinced me. All my questions are still some lessions i am learing... You helped me alot . thx for your patience! GREAT Community here - with very gentil folks btw. greetings zero